# Show the set of open sets with respect to a metric defines a Topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have just started my first week of functional analysis, and I have never taken a topology course so I'm struggling a bit. I have to prove the following:

> Let $(X,\rho)$ be a metric space. Show $\mathcal{K}=\{A\subset X; A$ open with respect to $\rho\}$ defines a topology on $X$.

I have already done a lot of work on this proof but I am stuck right now showing that the intersection of two open sets generates another open set (condition 2 of a topology). What I have done so far:

(i) case 1 where $\mathbb{O}_1\cap \mathbb{O}_2=\varnothing$ is fine since $\varnothing$ is in $\mathbb{K}$

(ii) case 2 where $\mathbb{O}_1\cap \mathbb{O}_2=\mathbb{O}_1$ or $\mathbb{O}_2$ is fine because $\mathbb{O}_1$ and $\mathbb{O}_2$ are in $\mathbb{K}$

(iii) case 3 where $\mathbb{O}_1\cap \mathbb{O}_2=M$ where M is the collection of points contained in $\mathbb{O}_1$ and $\mathbb{O}_2$. Now we want to show that M is open with respect to $\rho$, meaning that for any arbitrary $w\in M \Rightarrow \exists B(w,\epsilon)\subset M$.

This is where I am getting stuck. I feel like what I need to do is to show that since $w\in \mathbb{O}_1$ and $\mathbb{O}_2$ that I already have $\exists B(w,\epsilon)\subset\mathbb{O}_1$ and $B(w,\epsilon^{'})\subset\mathbb{O}_2$, and maybe I need to use some form of the triangle inequality to force this inside of $M$, but I'm not sure to do this and Im also not sure if this is even the right way of doing it. Any advice? Thank yoU!

Comment: You're almost there. Define $\epsilon''=\min\{\epsilon,\epsilon'\}$. What can you say about $B(w,\epsilon'')$?

Comment: Oh my gosh. How silly of me. Yes, this gives it away right away. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: You're welcome. You can answer your own question so that it doesn't stay among the unanswered questions.